# How pull only 6 documents and with the value true in a field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this controller:

```
Model.find().sort('date').limit(6).exec(function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      res.send(result);
    }
});
```

In my schema, i have a field tof (true or false), and i want pull only 6 documents with the value true in the tof field, this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
Model.find({tof: true}).sort('date').limit(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use select condition like >

```
Model.find({'tof':true}).sort('date').limit(6).exec(function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        res.send(result);
    }
});
```